# What is the difference between short/byte inside a parameter and inside a block

Tags: java, compiler-construction, compiler-optimization, short

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Eclipse bug? When is a short not a short?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14297113/eclipse-bug-when-is-a-short-not-a-short)

In Java I can assign a `short` or a `byte` inside blocks like this:

```
short s = 20000;
byte  b = 120;
```

Because 20000 is a `short` value and 120 is a `byte` value, if I attempt to try:

```
short s = 67000;
byte  b = 128;
```

I will get an error that states it cannot compile from `int` to `byte` where

```
byte b = (byte)12232;
```

will not even trigger a warning that value may get lost. In a function call I'm forced to cast it anyways:

```
void test(short s){}
test(1) //invalid
test((short)1) //valid
```

While on `return` types it is okay again.

```
short test(){
    return 1; //valid
}
```

Why does the compiler sometimes deside to know the bounds of numbers (at least from constants), while it seem that it forgets it elsewhere?

Comment: @assylias a very nice spotting, have you memorized all java questions? +1

Comment: uh, well I don't found that question, too :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Integral numeric literals in Java are of just two kinds: `int` (which are declared as `123`), and `long` (which are declared as `123L`).

- `short s = 1` is allowed because it is an assignment and a narrow conversion is allowed there
- `short s = 67000` doesn't work because you are exceeding the maximum value that can rapresented with a `short`
- `short s = (short)67000` works because you are placing a cast so you are explicitly requesting the type checker to ignore the fact that 67000 exceeds the maximum value
- `test(1)` doesn't work because it's a method invocation, a narrow conversion is not allowed (int -> short) and `1` is always evaluated as an integer literal by the compiler