# short narrowing conversion in a method

Tags: java, methods, short

As explained in the answers to this question: [Eclipse bug? When is a short not a short?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14297113/eclipse-bug-when-is-a-short-not-a-short) 
It is not legal in a method to implicitly narrow convert an int to a short. And that was related to passing an int as an argument where the parameter in the method was a short.

However it appears that for the return type things are different.

```
public short doStuff(){
System.out.println("ciao");
return 4;
}
```

It still is in the method scope even though it is going to be assigned outside the method (maybe this is the reason why).
However being a little puzzled about it, I would ask your view about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works because it's a literal constant.  This will give a compiler error:

```
public short doStuff(int test)
{
    System.out.println("ciao");
    return test;  // error
}
```

Comment: Why it is true for the return values but it is not for the argument? Still if I put an int literal instad of a variable name in the arguments it gives me an error whereas in the return field if i put the literal int it goes smooth with a very good narrowing conversion.