# Java: must cast to short, cannot use shorthand 'S'

Tags: java, casting, java-7, short

I am trying to call a function that requires a short value. The following works:

```
i.setDamage((short) 10);
```

However, this does not:

```
i.setDamage(10S);
```

According to the IDE I am using, this should work. Why does it not? I am using Maven and Java 7.

Comment: The fact that you are using Maven has no bearing on your question. Maven is not a compiler- it uses a compiler. Thus it doesn't really care about the syntax of your code.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what IDE is this that thinks Java allows an `S` suffix for integer literals?

Comment: @augray Ok, thank you for clearing that up. I didn't really know what part of the process maven did.

Comment: @Ted Hopp I am using Eclipse, and it accepted '10S' when I needed a short as a function argument.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the [Java Language Specification, Section 3.10.1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.1), the only integer type suffix for integer literals is `L` (or lower case `l`).

> An integer literal is of type long if it is suffixed with an ASCII letter L or l (ell); otherwise it is of type int ([§4.2.1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.2.1)).
>
> <sub>The suffix L is preferred, because the letter l (ell) is often hard to distinguish from the digit 1 (one).</sub>

You'll just have to stick with a cast. (Although you may be able to just use the integer literal without a cast if the value is in range.)

Comment: See also this [related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2294934/setting-short-value-java).

Comment: And this [oracle nutsandbolts](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html)

Comment: [This thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14297113/eclipse-bug-when-is-a-short-not-a-short) also has a bit of useful info about when you need to cast and when you can use an `int` literal without casting when you need a `short`.

Answer (score 0):

According to the Java Language the long value will only hold the suffix of L.

Refer

[Java Primitive Data types](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html)

Answer (score 0):

JAVA doesn't provide any suffix like `S` or `s` for `short`. You need to cast to `short`using `(short)100`.

Possible values are

```
int num = 20; //Decimal
int num = 020; //octal
int num = 0x20; //Hexadecimal
int num = 0b1010; //binary
long num = 563L; //long
```

In JDK 7, you can embed one or more underscores in an integer literal like

```
int num = 19_90;
```

Comment: Don't use code formatting for text that isn't code.

Comment: You can also use an `L` suffix for octal, hex, or binary literals (e.g., `0b1010L`).